# Testing package exports using 'testthat'

Tags: r, namespaces, testthat

**Question:** How can I get `testthat` to run in an environment that *loads* my package, rather than *inherits from* my package?

**Background:** The `testthat` package runs tests "in an environment that inherits from the package's namespace environment" [see the docs for [test_check](https://github.com/hadley/testthat/blob/master/R/test-package.r)].  This means it doesn't make sure I've done my exports correctly, and that's bitten me several times.

For example, I have the following code in my package:

```
##' The foo() method
##' @param x object
##' @export
foo <- function(x)
  UseMethod('foo')

##' @rdname foo
foo.data.frame <- function(x) {
  message("foo data.frame")
}

##' @rdname foo
foo.default <- function(x) {
  message("foo default")
}
```

And the following in my tests:

```
x <- 5:13
foo(x)
```

That tests just fine.  But if a user installs the package, they'll get this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("foo") : 
  no applicable method for 'foo' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

The solution is to put `@exports` declarations for the two methods, but it's a bummer that the tests didn't catch that.

I would much prefer to run all my tests from the point of view of a user, because I tend to screw up my exporting sometimes.  Perhaps an option could be added to `testthat:::run_tests` that selects which behavior is desired?

Answer (score 1):

Use `test_dir`.  I don't use `test_check` for this exact reason.  In "/tests/run-tests.R" (file name doesn't matter, it just needs to be in that directory and end in ".R") write:

```
library(testthat)
library(<my package>)  # insert actual package name here
test_dir('testthat')   # assuming your tests are in "tests/testthat"
```

Then, in order to run your tests:

```
setwd("<pkg dir>/tests")
source("run-tests.R")
```

Or from the command line:

```
cd <pkg-dir>/tests
Rscript run-tests.R
```

Or do `R CMD build` and `R CMD check` to run the tests that way.

The `setwd` is not strictly necessary if your tests don't care about working directory.  However, if they do doing so will replicate the working directory set by `R CMD check`.